# Safari position:sticky not working in an overflow:auto element

Tags: css, safari, overflow, sticky

According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky), there is a known issue with Safari and `position:sticky` inside an `overflow:auto` element:

> A parent with overflow set to auto will prevent position: sticky from working in Safari

However, this is the exact use case that I need. I have a scrollable div, which is subdivided into two columns. The right column should be sticky and never move, even when the entire div is scrolled. The reason I'm using `position:sticky` on the right column is that I want the user to be able to still scroll the left column with the cursor on the right column. And this was the only solution that I found to have worked.

A working example for Firefox / Chrome is here:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/zfiuz4pc
The orange area remains fixed while scrolling, but in Safari it doesn't.

The example above has some unnecessary wrappers to my issue, but I wanted to replicate as closely as possible the environment where I want to have this code working in. The basic gist of it is I have this:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="left-content">
  </div>
  <div class="sticky-element">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.left-content {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}

.sticky-element {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Again, this works in FF/Chrome but not in Safari. Is there a workaround to get it to work in all browsers? Or is there a different approach I can use to maintain scrollability even with the mouse cursor over the sticky element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this solution from someone else:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/bu0nx69w

Basically, instead of `position:sticky`, use `position:fixed` for the right panel. The key is to also you `will-change:transform` in a parent div (in the above example, in `.modal-content`) so `position:fixed` becomes fixed relative to that parent, and not the viewport. It's a neat little trick

Comment: You might have solved your use case but have you found why `sticky` wasn't working ?

Comment: @Laura It's only Safari's implementation of sticky. It simply doesn't work in this specific scenario of `overflow:auto;` and `position:sticky` that Safari doesn't handle. Hence this workaround which uses `position:fixed` instead.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, I had a much more complicated layout where the first and last columns were static, the middle columns needed to scroll horizontally if there were too many, and the whole first row needed to stick to the top of the screen. I ended up using this trick for the middle columns, and was able to keep the first and last columns' top row sticky.

Comment: Unfortunately, this eliminates interactivity in the sticky element, because of the `z-index: -1`.  It's a nice trick though.

Answer (score 34):

simply add `position: -webkit-sticky;`

Comment: @debanjanB you're right, here's my explanation. At the moment, Safari only support this feature with the prefix `-webkit-`. Maybe this link will help you understand https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: Also for Safari, the sticky element needs to be a block-level element (or use `display: block`).

I was was trying to make a `<button>` sticky, but it wasn't working in Safari because buttons are `inline-block` by default.

Answer (score 9):

Adding `display: block` to the `.sticky-element` worked for me without having to add `position: -webkit-sticky`. Found this solution at [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/wmrNJK).

Comment: Thanks man, I was having an issue with Sticky/Position Bottom in Safari ...and `display: block;` on the sticky element worked a treat! No idea why but seems to have done the job!

Comment: FWIW I'm actually a woman :) Really glad it worked for you, it's a neat fix!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar case:

```
<div scroll>
    <div sticky />
    <list />
</div>
```

**Just wrap the scroll content with a div worked like a charm:**

```
<div scroll>
    <div>
       <div sticky />
       <list />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to use below to make it work in both Chrome and Safari:

```
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
display: block;
```

Comment: For me, on iPhone with software version 14.7, it doesn't work.
On iPhone with software version 15.2.1, it works.

Answer (score 1):

`position: sticky` will not work, if your parent element has `overflow: hidden`. having this `sticky` setting, it will have automatically transform your element from `relative to actual fixed` to the top border of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this specific case, so long as you don't need the scroll bar on the far right of the modal.

Since your sticky element is the same height as your `.modal-content`, you could remove sticky altogether from `.sticky-element`. First, remove overflow:auto from `.modal-content`, then add that style to `.left-content` since that's the part you want to scroll anyway.

Comment: Realized right after posting this the OP wants to be able to scroll the left side while over the fixed section to the right. This wouldn't allow for that either.

Answer (score -1):

i cant really test this for safari right now but this has always been an alternative for me when creating a sticky footer for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sticky side div</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .maindiv{
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: forestgreen;
            width: calc(100vw - 150px);
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .sidediv{
            position: fixed;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: lightyellow;
            float: right;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="maindiv">
        Lorem 45    
    </div>
    <div class="sidediv">
        Lorem 30
    </div>
    <div class="maindiv">
        Lorem 100
    </div>
    <div class="maindiv">
        Lorem 900
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

once you know the width of your right content add a little more px to it then use the css `calc function` to make sure the other div's don't flow in to it

also there is a known bug with vh and vw in Safari 7. You can fix it by setting height: inherit on the #child elements whose parents have `vh` heights or `vw` widths

but my best recommendation if you were not going for cross browser support will be to use `CSS Grids`

Comment: I tried your markup, and it worked only as is. But if I add a parent element with `position:absolute`, the right panel is not positioned correctly. I posted a solution that I just got from someone else that suits my needs.