# sticky-top does not work with Angular8/safari

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, safari, mobile-safari

I want to use [Sticky top](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/#sticky-top) of bootstrap4.

It works fine on Chrome/Firefox, but not on Safari on Mac or iPhone.
I understand that it doesn't work with Angular components, but I don't know the cause.
How can I get it to work?

---

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

header.component.html

```
<div class="sticky-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">TEST</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-success">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">
      test
    </a>
    <div href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-auto">test</div>
    <div class="nav-link" href="#"></div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
...
```

---

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2dmga)

- Safari:13.0.3 (14608.3.10.10.1)
- Angular:8.2.14
- bootstrap: 4.3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari position:sticky not working in an overflow:auto element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792783/safari-positionsticky-not-working-in-an-overflowauto-element)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [**Bootstrap Docs**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/#sticky-top):

> ## Sticky top
>
> Position an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge, but only after you scroll past it. The `.sticky-top` utility uses CSS’s position: sticky, which isn’t fully supported in all browsers.
>
> **IE11 and IE10 will render** `position: sticky` as `position: relative`. As such, we wrap the styles in a @supports query, limiting the stickiness to only browsers that can render it properly.

And this is also the case with Safari.

As a matter of fact, according to [**CanIUse**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), safari only supports this with a `-webkit-` prefix.

So you might want to add that to a css class and apply it on the `div`.

Try adding this css class in the `header.component.css`:

```
.sticky-top {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}
```

> Here's a [**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsajzd?file=src/app/header/header.component.css) for your ref.