# CSS drop-down menu with search function - pinning search bar to top

Tags: css

I'm trying to make it so the search box (#myInput) in this drop-down menu is pinned to the top as users scroll through the selection menu, similar to "freezing" a row in Excel.

Is it possible to have this functionality using CSS without completely separating the search box from the menu options? Or will I have to look at other options to keep the search box pinned?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">.dropbtn {
  background-color: #A41E34;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 20px;
  border: none;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 1px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 420px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
<div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Select an Option</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown"><input id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" placeholder="Search..." type="text"> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 1</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 2</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 3</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 4</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 5</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 6</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 7</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 8</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 1</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 2</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 3</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 4</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify your code, all I did was add two lines to the CSS for the `#myInput` element. Without the top margin removed, there was a bit of text showing when scrolling through the list. I also added padding to the second child element, based on the values of the text size + top and bottom padding.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">.dropbtn {
  background-color: #A41E34;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: initial;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  position: sticky;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 1px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 420px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
<div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Select an Option</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown"><input id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" placeholder="Search..." type="text"> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 1</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 2</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 3</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 4</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 5</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 6</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 7</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Option 8</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 1</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 2</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 3</a> <a href="https://www.google.com">Choice 4</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I added those two lines to the CSS for that element, but it seems to have layered the search bar on top of the first menu item, making it not visible.

Comment: I added padding to the second child element—this displays properly now.

Comment: Perfect! This works how I wanted it to. Thanks for the solution. Now I'm noticing that the border of the search bar extends past the menu when it is selected for text input. Additionally, when the search function is used, the first result row is hidden underneath the search bar.

Comment: OK—added another minor edit—positioning changed from fixed to sticky.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick - I just had to add top: 0;

In order to get this to work on Safari, I added the following:

position: -webkit-sticky;

However, when I tested on an iPhone on the newest version of Safari, the search bar is not staying stickied. Could it be due to overflow: auto; in the dropdown element?

Comment: Did some more checking—based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792783/safari-positionsticky-not-working-in-an-overflowauto-element), adding display:block was needed on the element because Safari treats it as inline-block by default.

Answer (score 0):

As other way around, you can use Bootstrap-Select plugin. It has all the thing.
Check it [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/).